# Border position- does not work.

Tags: html, css, border

CSS:

```
 .poziomy a{
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 23px;
  fotnt-weight: 400;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-style: dashed;
  color: #1a1a1a;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 70px;
  padding-right: 70px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  z-index: 1100;

}

.poziomy a:hover{
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 23px;
  fotnt-weight: 400;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #00bca4;
  border-style: dashed;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 71px;
  padding-right: 71px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  z-index: 1100;
}

#poziom1{
  top: 2100px;
  left: 20%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="poziom1" class="poziomy">
<a href="http://www.google.pl"> Poziom 1
</a></div>
```

The div doesn't show at -top: 2100px but somewhere else like in the middle of the site which I dont wnat to. Don't know why.

Somebody can help or have some ideas what to change?

Comment: You've misspelled font `fotnt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the positioning of what you want to move to relative or absolute. use

```
position: absolute;
```

so you will end up with

```
#poziom1{
  top: 2100px;
  left: 20%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

p.s. fotnt-weight: 400; should be font-weight: 400; its in your code x2

Comment: .must be tired.. dont know how i missed it. Thx everyone

Answer (score 0):

You need to add position: absolute to your div.

See http://jsfiddle.net/FnKrV/

```
position: absolute;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if div's parent has a `position:relative` rule, and set the div to `position:absolute`. Or, if you want to have it always fixed, you can set his `position` value to `fixed`

Answer (score 0):

```
 #poziom1 {
     top: 2100px;
     left: 20%;
     width: 300px;
     height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mX4E5/1/